# JS ask user to enable cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies

My website needs cookies to run. I noticed I can prompt the user to enable cookies with a pop-up that looks something like this:

example.com website wants to
enable cookies

allow -------------- deny

Is it possible to trigger this with JS/JQuery? Or is the pop-up just a scam and baits people to click one of the buttons?